# React Router - Mounting component inside a nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having a hard time figuring out how to mount components inside a nested components with react router v1.0. I have an App component that loads a Layout component. The Layout component then loads two components, Menu and Content. I want to load different components inside the Content component based on the route.

Below is my sample code.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
         return <div><Layout/></div>
     }
});

var Layout = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Menu/>
                <Content/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Content = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return <div>This is where i want to mount my components</div>
    }
});

var List = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return <div>some list goes here</div>
    }
});

var Graph = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return <div>some graph goes here</div>
    }
});

<Router>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <Route path='/list' component={List}/>
        <Route path='/graph' component={Graph}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all the same as basic React components. When you nest them, they're available on `this.props.children`. So you would end up with something like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
         return <div><Layout>{this.props.children}</Layout></div>
     }
});

var Layout = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Menu/>
                <Content>{this.props.children}</Content>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Content = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    }
});
```

Comment: Do'h! Of course, sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Thank You Tim